# eslint error "guard-for-in" not clear how to work with for-in

Tags: javascript, automation, cucumber, eslint, for-in-loop

I'm working with cucumber js and I want to fill out some fields in an application, so i'm using a for-in to get the data from the rowHash but i'm getting the error message "The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype  guard-for-in" i'm not sure how I should code my for-in with the if inside the for.

this is my code:

```
this.fillRequiredfields = function(dataTable){
  var rows = dataTable.rowsHash();
  for (var row in rows) {
    var val = rows[row];

    if (row === 'firstname') {
      element(by.name('firstName')).sendKeys(val).isPresent();
    }
    if (row === 'lastname') {
      element(by.name('lastName')).sendKeys(val).isPresent();
    }
    if (row === 'emailaddress') {
      element(by.name('emailAddress')).sendKeys(val).isPresent();
    }
    if (row === 'displayname') {
      element(by.name('displayName')).sendKeys(val).isPresent();
    }
    if (row === 'password') {
      element(by.name('newPassword')).sendKeys(val).isPresent();
    }
  }
};
```

So when I try to do the commit in git i'm getting the "guard-for-in" from eslint. If somebody can explain me how I should do the if in the for-in that could be good.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: The [eslint documentation for this rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/guard-for-in) has an example of correct usage.

Comment: Yeah but i don't get what is mean the "    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, key)) {
        doSomething(key);
    }"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I already solve this, in my case the solution was:

instead of

```
var val = rows[row];
```

I add the if with the hasOwnProperty(), like this:

```
if (rows.hasOwnProperty(row))
```

So the code is like this:

```
for (var row in rows) {
  if (rows.hasOwnProperty(row)){

    if (row === 'firstname') {
      element(by.name('firstName')).sendKeys(rows[row]).isPresent();
    }
    if (row === 'lastname') {
      element(by.name('lastName')).sendKeys(rows[row]).isPresent();
    }
    if (row === 'emailaddress') {
      element(by.name('emailAddress')).sendKeys(rows[row]).isPresent();
    }
    if (row === 'displayname') {
      element(by.name('displayName')).sendKeys(rows[row]).isPresent();
    }
    if (row === 'password') {
      element(by.name('newPassword')).sendKeys(rows[row]).isPresent();
    }
  }
}
```

Hope can help to somebody else.

Answer (score 5):

In some rare cases

```
if (rows.hasOwnProperty(row))
```

might trigger undesired effect (for example if this is a function hasOwnProperty()). So this is why suggested method is

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(rows, row)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `for...of` statement (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) so your code would be something like:

```
for (var row of Object.keys(rows)) {
  if (row === 'firstname') {
    element(by.name('firstName')).sendKeys(rows[row]).isPresent();
  }
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation of getting around `guard-for-in` using an array method.

```
Object.entries(rows).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (value === 'firstname') {
    element(by.name('firstName')).sendKeys(val).isPresent();
  }
  // ...
});
```